# Simple Desktop application to change windows 10 settings

Tags: windows, desktop-application

is there a way to write an application (for example in C#) that could change windows 10 settings?

The idea is that I often use Blue Light Filter and other users of my computer don't like it, so I would like to write an very simple app that I could just click on and it would turn this one setting on and off. So that I don't need to go to settings and manually change it every time

please let me know if that's possible or if there's any other way to achive it

Comment: Sure, just go ahead and write some code. Stackoverflow doesn't work well with such broad questions as yours (assuming you'd want to know how to do this, not just whether it's possible); see [ask]. You could look for some tutorials and start writing code. When you run into specific problems, come back and ask here. Include your code as a [mcve]. Good luck!